# Can't understand logic with layouts size for all resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I read many opinions about that, but in practice, after creating all layouts folders with (`ldpi`,`mdpi`,`hdpi` e.t.c.) and correction all of it, my layout's elements didn't stay on the one point. Now I'm trying to work with `ConstrantLayout`, and did all bindings,that I can, but again. If that mean, that for exelent result on each display, I need each possible combination of Display resolution/Display size. It's logical, but it so many..

**EDITED**: Problems only with TextViews...
I found that, my phone with low resolution still used layuot for xxxhdpi, and problem I think in this. I read about adding to `Manifest` `<support-screen>`construction, but I'm not sure that this right way to slove my problem..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cards">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="227dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/black_h" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_confirm"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/TransperantColor"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
        android:src="@drawable/confirm_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/confirm_light" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_home"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/TransperantColor"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
        android:src="@drawable/home_light"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/head_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"         
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/card_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/head_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mon_fri_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sat_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sun_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.008"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/decription_text"
        android:layout_width="353dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sun_text" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:scaleX="0.8"
        android:scaleY="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/decription_text"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/phone_ico" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:scaleX="0.8"
        android:scaleY="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/geo_ico" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone1_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/decription_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone2_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone1_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextColor"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.025"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone2_name" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Usually you don't need layouts for all configurations (like hdpi, xhdpi etc.). Just create your layouts in the "layout" folder. You don't have to care about each possible combination of display resolution and size. And you should not use "px" for dimensions, better use "dp", then Android will scale the UI on each device properly.

Comment: You can use weights in your simple layouts for responsive layout creation.. 
in that case you will not have to make more screens . moreover its easy.

Comment: I want to ask if there are the only solution, to add tens of layout, i'm not professional in it@B001ᛦ

Comment: I think in your way, but in practise I havn't good result. My 2 phones, can't give me right layout. I used "dp" and maybe problem in bindings?@Headcracker

Comment: @Headcracker and there are no problem with `buttons` or `imageview`. The problem only with `TextViews`... I gave one layout for exaple..

Comment: I would go with ScrollView as parent. Some phones will be okay without scrolling, some will have to scroll. Otherwise you will have to change play with weights or with other configurations

Answer (score 0):

I will share what I found in my research, if in any way I'm wrong, feel free to edit or correct. My main source is this [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes).

AFAIK the mdpi, hdpi etc. are more suitable for drawable resources, where different pixel densities need to be supported. When dealing with screen sizes there are two options to consider when creating different layouts:

**1) Smallest width** - enables you to provide different layouts based on a minimum width measured in dps. According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources):

> You can use this qualifier to ensure that, regardless of the screen's current orientation, your app's has at least  dps of width available for its UI.

When providing layout resources for it, it looks like this `layout-sw600dp`

**2) Available width** - providing layout based on how much width is currently available.

> you can use this to specify the minimum width required for the layout, instead of using both the screen size and orientation qualifiers together. This is often useful to determine whether to use a multi-pane layout.

It looks like this `layout-w600dp`.

Here are some sizes that you can provide for:

> 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
>   480dp: a large phone screen ~5" (480x800 mdpi).
>   600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
>   720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

But I believe in order to understand the concept completely you need to read the documentation starting from [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support) page.

Comment: I read many info about this, but try to go way with layout-(ldpi,mdpi e.t.c.) and dimensions for all this layouts. Don't know is this realy optimal way but anywhere..@LieForBananas I just want to know how that did professionals.

Comment: In degin I used ConstraintsLayout, and it was a mess,when I try to launch this on other phines, but when I choose standart Layout(Linear/Relative) even without any different folders, it's look like very good on much of devices, that I tested.@LieForBananas

Comment: The problem is that my phone, for example, that have hdpi resolution, take layout not from this folder, but with folder with more high resolution, and I didn't know, what did with that..@LieForBananas

Comment: @SpikeJohnson I don't know why you had such experience with `ConstraintLayout`, it's supposed to be an upgrade of a `RelativeLayout`. The reason why your phone may take from a different folder is the screen size, look at [this](https://material.io/tools/devices/) page, some screens have same densities but different screen sizes. At least I believe it's that, try using smallest width, I think it's the way to go.

Comment: I verify, that phone take right layout, but location of elements some different of it on device. But the in "device in Editor" choosed right phone as my real, with same resolution and size of display..@LieForBananas

Comment: @SpikeJohnson It may be related to the theme that you have chosen in your layout design view, try changing the theme there.

Comment: @LieForBananas here is +1 just for you to stop lying

Comment: @Eminem not for nothing though :)